# match last digits in a long number with regex

Tags: regex

I'm real newbie when it comes to Regex so apologies if this 'should' be easy.

I need to match the last 6 digits of a number that has the following format

> 308950 3200 014559

The first 2 groups of numbers will remain constant (308950 3200) and don't need to be extracted. I am only interested in the last 6 digits.

The full number may contain spaces but these need to be optional.

This has to be done in Regex.

Comment: Where is your effort? What have you tried?

Comment: You need to show a level of effort.

Comment: Why should this be a RegEx? Why don't you only take the 6 last characters from this string?

Answer (score 0):

If the leading numbers will remain constant, you can use:

```
308950 3200\s*(\d{6})
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
(?:\d+\s)+(\d{6})
```

Also, if the string will be at the *end* of the input string, consider adding a `$` to the end to signify this (to make sure it'll match the end of the string):

```
(\d{6})$
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it even if there are spaces between the digits

```
^308950 3200[\d\s]*?((\d\s?){6})$
```

Group 1 will contain the reqired digits with spaces if any

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern

```
(?<=\b308950\s*3200\s*)\d{6}\b
```

or

```
\b308950\s*3200\s*(\d{6})\b
```